# What is omitted in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Maintain a faster walking speed than is natural for you.

(This sentence is quoted from the book "*Thinking, fast and slow*", p. 22., by Daniel Kahneman.)

- Is **what** is omitted in "**than (what) is natural for you.**"?
- Is this kind of omission common in English?

Comment: Hello, Jin, notice that you have duplicated the verb "is" in your first question. The second "is" is not necessary.

Comment: Hello Rubio. I got your point but this is the quoted sentence from the book I mentioned above. I changed nothing in this sentence.

Comment: "Is what is omitted in "than (what) is natural for you."?" should be "Is what omitted in "than (what) is natural for you."?" Notice that I have removed the second "is"

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks. And I'm sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal to omit words from a sentence, and not change its meaning.
The general term for this is [ellipsis](http://www.literarydevices.com/ellipsis/), which has two definitions:

- A series of three dots indicating words deliberately omitted from a quotation.
- The omission of words that are understood and thus unnecessary.

The second definition applies here, and the full sentence can be

> Maintain a faster walking speed than **what** is natural for you.
>
> Maintain a faster walking speed than **the speed that** is natural for you.

It is common to omit words from a sentence and still retain its meaning.